# What should be the type of my profile picture for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, profile-picture

I just joined Stack Overflow, and while setting my profile I uploaded my picture for the profile, but it is giving this error:

[image]

Comment: Questions about Stack Overflow should be posted  on [meta]. This site is for programming related questions. You can find more information in the [help].

Comment: Furthermore, images of error messages are poor practice. Copy/paste the error message text into the question; and, if the message suggests that your image is invalid, perhaps link to or embed the actual profile image so we can see for ourselves.

Comment: Note that the proposed duplicate explains format-agnostically, i.e. it is not relevant whether yours was a gif or not.